# Webpack 2 - compile scss to css and miniffy, together with sourcemaps

Tags: source-maps, sass-loader, webpack-2

I'm completely new to webpack (been using gulp since... forever).

However, I've just decided to use webpack. Decided to go with webpack 2 (2.1.0-beta.20 currently). 
Been looking all over, still couldn't do a simple task as "give webpack my `bootstrap.scss` file (which imports all other bootstrap partial scss files needed) and have returned `bootstrap.custom.min.css` and `bootstrap.custom.min.css.map`".

I have my own `bootstrap.scss` file which only imports what I need from bootstrap (not using all of it), but after a custom `custom-variables.scss` file imported at the top, to overwrite some default bootstrap variables - like colors, grid columns etc. Anyway, I'm sure this is not relevant... The issue is compiling `scss` to `css` with custom output file name and sourcemap.

Not that it would make any difference, but to start with, here's my custom `bootstrap.scss`:

```
@import "custom-variables"; // to overwrite default bootstrap variables
/**
 * Twitter Bootstrap
 * This is actually copy/paste from the original bootstrap file, just changed paths
 */
// Core variables and mixins
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
// and so on... only what I need. I don't need tables, forms and a few other.
```

In addition to this, I also have my own `style.scss` for which I need to do the same (to have returned `style.min.css` and `style.min.css.map`).

As for my `webpack.config.js` file, this is all I have:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const sassLoaders = [
    'css-loader',
    'postcss-loader',
    'sass-loader?indentedSyntax=sass&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './dev')
];

const config = {
    entry: {
        'bootstrap.custom.min': ['./wp-bootstrap'], // this file only contains 1 line: require('./dev/css/overwrite/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss');
        'style.min': ['./wp-style'], // this file also contains 1 line: require('./dev/css/style.scss');
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'file',
                // or, other examples I've found said to use:
                // loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loaders: 'css!sass' }),
                // but if I try like that, I get: "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined"
                query: {
                   name: '[name].css'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],
    postcss: [
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./'),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

These are all the related packages I have installed:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.20"
  }
```

If I use a version of extract-text-webpack-plugin which is <2.x, then I get other errors, it's not compatible with webpack 2.

So, baby steps in the code above... Simply tried to at least obtain my `bootstrap.scss` and `style.scss` transformed into 2 separate css files: `bootstrap.custom.min.css` and `style.min.css` (don't know what to do about sourcemaps yet).

This is all I could come up with after searching google and trying to follow some examples. No solid tutorial out there that could make me understand how to use webpack for what I need to accomplish. I'm only guessing here, blind-folded.

But when I type `webpack` in the console and hit Enter, I don't get any css file, instead I get the following 3 files:

1. `bootstrap.css` - with the exact same content as the source
   `bootstrap.scss`, like it just copies the file content over, instead of compiling scss to css;
2. `bootstrap.custom.min.js` which has a bunch of javascript code in
   it;
3. `style.min.js` - which also has a bunch of javascript code in it.

I've been stuck here for days, didn't even get to all the rest I need (sourcemaps and a destination folder of my choosing for the css files and css.map files).

Comment: Any updates on this? Facing the same.

Comment: @Kevin no luck. Because of that, to this day, I'm still using Gulp.

Comment: this helped me out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660422/cannot-read-property-query-of-undefined-extract-text-webpack-plugin/42660733?noredirect=1#comment72461339_42660733